# Git trying to push with MacOS username rather than config name

Tags: git, macos, github, terminal

I pushed to a repository a few days ago successfully.  I'm not sure what happened, but now attempts to push are throwing

```
SlyMachine:travel-site dev$ git push origin
dev@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My Mac username is `dev`, and the 1st line of the error is showing `dev@github.com`, which is where I assume it is getting it from.

My global config at ~/.gitconfig just has my name/email.

This is my local config at .git/config:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://github.com/danfoust/travel-site.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lied in my local config.

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://github.com/danfoust/travel-site.git
```

I grabbed the url syntax from somewhere and it was incorrect or outdated.  As per [GitHub's Help page](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/), I had to set the remote user to `git`:

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:danfoust/travel-site.git`

That fixed the issue.

Comment: You can also spell this `ssh://git@github.com/danfoust/travel-site.git`. Of course that's *longer*, but at least it starts with a URL "scheme" (whatever://) string... :-)